# Как сделать рандомный рандом в C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, случайные-числа, .net

Чтот меня смущает рандом...

```
public class Rand
{
    List<int> tmp = new List<int>();
    int max;
    int[] array;

    public Rand(int max)
    {
        this.max = max;
        array = new int[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.max; i++)
        {
            tmp.Add(i);                          
        }
    }

    public int[] Next()
    {
        int t;

        for (int i = max-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            t = new Random().Next(i);
            array[i] = tmp[t];
            tmp.RemoveAt(t);
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Почему рандом всегда выглядит как-то так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слишком уж не рандомно

А если о задачи в целом то нужно сделать массив рандомных чисел, но так чтобы числа не повторялись

Comment: Если предложенный дубликат не подходит - тогда видимо вам нужно объяснить, какой закон распределения случайных чисел вы хотите видеть (нормальное распределение или что-то более специфическое).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> t = new Random().Next(i);
> ```

Выноси генератор в отдельную переменную (можно даже в статическое поле) и не пересоздавай.

Comment: Превеликое спасибо, ваш ответ сделал рандом более рандомным, вот только последнее число все равно 1999 всегда, а с остальным все даже не плохо, но это думаю уже мой косяк (как и предыдущий)

Comment: @Matrzaei Рандом никогда не отдаёт число равное верхней границе - и это явно описано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-2.0).

Comment: Окееей, спасиб ещё раз, очень помогли)